# Cannot seem to install mysql on mac

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rubygems

```
sudo gem install mysql — –with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/optparse.rb:1262: warning: regexp match /.../n against to UTF-8 string
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/optparse.rb:1278: warning: regexp match /.../n against to UTF-8 string
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/optparse.rb:1262: warning: regexp match /.../n against to UTF-8 string
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/optparse.rb:1278: warning: regexp match /.../n against to UTF-8 string
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for mysql_ssl_set()... no
checking for rb_str_set_len()... no
checking for rb_thread_start_timer()... no
checking for mysql.h... yes
creating Makefile

make
gcc -I. -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/i386-darwin9.8.0 -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -DHAVE_MYSQL_H  -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -I/usr/local/mysql/include/mysql -D_P1003_1B_VISIBLE -DSIGNAL_WITH_VIO_CLOSE -DSIGNALS_DONT_BREAK_READ -DIGNORE_SIGHUP_SIGQUIT  -DDONT_DECLARE_CXA_PURE_VIRTUAL -fno-common  -O2 -g -Wall -Wno-parentheses -pipe -fno-common  -o mysql.o -c mysql.c
In file included from /usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby.h:32,
                 from mysql.c:5:
/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h: In function ‘INT2NUM’:
/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:464: warning: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type
/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:464: warning: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type
/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h: In function ‘UINT2NUM’:
/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:472: warning: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type
mysql.c: In function ‘escape_string’:
mysql.c:290: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
mysql.c:290: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
mysql.c: In function ‘real_escape_string’:
mysql.c:434: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
mysql.c:434: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
make: *** [mysql.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql-2.8.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql-2.8.1/ext/mysql_api/gem_make.out
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem '—' (>= 0) in any repository
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem '–with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config' (>= 0) in any repository
```

After doing the suggestion below I still get an error.

```
sudo gem install mysql —- –-with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/optparse.rb:1262: warning: regexp match /.../n against to UTF-8 string
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/optparse.rb:1278: warning: regexp match /.../n against to UTF-8 string
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/optparse.rb:1262: warning: regexp match /.../n against to UTF-8 string
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/optparse.rb:1278: warning: regexp match /.../n against to UTF-8 string
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for mysql_ssl_set()... yes
checking for rb_str_set_len()... no
checking for rb_thread_start_timer()... no
checking for mysql.h... yes
creating Makefile

make
gcc -I. -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/i386-darwin9.8.0 -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -DHAVE_MYSQL_SSL_SET -DHAVE_MYSQL_H  -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -I/usr/local/mysql/include  -g -Os -arch x86_64 -fno-common   -D_P1003_1B_VISIBLE -DSIGNAL_WITH_VIO_CLOSE -DSIGNALS_DONT_BREAK_READ -DIGNORE_SIGHUP_SIGQUIT  -DDONT_DECLARE_CXA_PURE_VIRTUAL -fno-common  -O2 -g -Wall -Wno-parentheses -pipe -fno-common  -o mysql.o -c mysql.c
In file included from /usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby.h:32,
                 from mysql.c:5:
/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h: In function ‘INT2NUM’:
/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:464: warning: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type
/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:464: warning: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type
/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h: In function ‘UINT2NUM’:
/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:472: warning: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type
mysql.c: In function ‘escape_string’:
mysql.c:290: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
mysql.c:290: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
mysql.c: In function ‘real_escape_string’:
mysql.c:434: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
mysql.c:434: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
make: *** [mysql.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql-2.8.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql-2.8.1/ext/mysql_api/gem_make.out
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem '—-' (>= 0) in any repository
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem '–-with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config' (>= 0) in any repository
```

Comment: BTW, don't use mysql gem with ruby 1.9.x as it doesn't support encodings properly. Use mysql2 gem instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be

```
sudo gem install mysql —- –-with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
```

not

```
sudo gem install mysql — –with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
```

(two hyphens between the gem name and build options, and two hyphens prefixing the build option)

You may also need to set the ARCHFLAGS variable. See [here](http://wonko.com/post/how-to-install-the-mysqlruby-gem-on-mac-os-x-leopard).

Answer (score 6):

You need mysql dev libraries installed as the mysql gem contains native code that is linked with them. The easiest way on mac is using brew - I've used it and it worked flawlessly but any good mac package manager can work (or you can install mysql from sources).

Brew installation: [Link](https://brew.sh/)
After it is installed just type:

```
brew install mysql
```

All brew recipies install dev libraries by default.

Comment: Brew is great, but if @jgervin isn't using it already, it's a lot of messing about just to install mysql. The binary package from the mysql site does just fine. No need to compile from source or use a new package management system.

Comment: Yeah, I agree, the important point is to install dev libraries in addition to normal libs. The advantage is that brew does that 'for free'.

Comment: The installers downloadable from mysql do it all for you too. It's just as easy to install as it is in brew. Well, if you don't have homebrew installed already, that is.

Comment: Awesome suggestion. It installs not only the dev and headers libraries but mysql_config and other mysql_* commands. Many Python and Ruby scripts around mysql need both. MAMP only ships with mysql_*, did not find the headers.

Comment: I did a `brew install mysql' and I was successful in installing the mysql . But I'm not able to find mysql development files `which mysql-devel` gives not found. How to I install the dev files?